# How to have \psframe working with LuaLatex?

Tags: luatex, pstricks

When I try to compile the code below in Overlef, I get an error if I set `LuaLaTeX` as `LaTeX Engine`, but no error if I set `Choose Automatically`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{pst-electricfield,multido} % campos elétricos

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-6)(6,6)
 \psframe*[linecolor=lightgray!50](-6,-6)(6,6)
 \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=gray,griddots=10]
 \psElectricfield[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=red]
 \psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=blue](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)
 \psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]}, linecolor=green, linewidth=2\pslinewidth, Vmax=0, Vmin=0](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

This is the error I get:

```
./main.tex:8: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps          
l.8  \psframe*[linecolor=lightgray!50](-6,-6)(6,6)
Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:  8148 strings out of 494688 ...
```

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't use PSTricks with LuaTeX. There are some ways around this; see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: The solutions work well with my MWE, but a lot of other errors appear when I apply them to a long document. I decided to compile PS pictures in a different project and to include them with `includegraphics`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run with `lualatex --shell-escape <file>`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf\else
  \usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\fi
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psframe*[linecolor=lightgray!50](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=gray,griddots=10]
    \psElectricfield[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=red]
    \psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 
    -2]},linecolor=blue](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)
    \psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]}, linecolor=green, 
    linewidth=2\pslinewidth, Vmax=0, Vmin=0](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to find how to put that compilation option in Overleaf.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291354/how-to-set-overleaf-to-compile-with-lualatex-shell-escape-file