# How to set Overleaf to compile with `lualatex --shell-escape <file>`?

Tags: luatex, pstricks, overleaf

I'm trying to use the solution given by the accepted answer in

[How to have \psframe working with LuaLatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291122/how-to-have-psframe-working-with-lualatex)

but I don't know how to enable the option --shell-escape there.

Overleaf explains that it has a configuration file called `latexmk`, but I don't understand a single line of it:

https://www.overleaf.com/help/216-how-does-overleaf-compile-my-project

I'm sorry if this is considered a `technical support` question. If I don't find a fast answer here, I'm going to contact Overleaf, but maybe this question helps somebody else here someday.

Comment: As the blog post in @Benjamin's answer says, `latexmkrc` and `--shell-escape` are allowed on Overleaf. Each Overleaf project is a Docker container (https://www.digital-science.com/blog/tech/intro-to-docker-and-how-we-use-it-at-overleaf/), so each project's settings and tricks stays within its own container.

Comment: Special case of [editors - How can I enable shell-escape? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-can-i-enable-shell-escape).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/216-examples-techniques-and-tips-on-how-to-use-latexmkrc-with-overleaf#.VrUnpcegjeQ) blog post, it should be possible to upload a `latexmkrc` file to your project and surprisingly even shell-escape seems to be allowed. I haven't tested it, but something like this should work:

```
$pdflatex = 'lualatex %O %S --shell-escape';
$pdf_mode = 1;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;
```