Setting main font, uncontrolled sequence error
I've been a LaTeX user for about 2 hours now and am completely lost on many things, but coming around. I'm using MikTeX on Windows, and writing the document through VSCode.
Specifically, I am trying to write a description of some calculations done by a program I'm writing, and I'm trying to play with the font of the main document.
I've set:
\usepackage{fontenc}
\begin{Document}
\setmainfont{Arial}

but this produces an error "Undefined control sequence." I do not know what a control sequence is in this context so I have no idea how to go about fixing this.
I've tried googling this error at length, and perhaps I walked right past the answer, but most of the results are about problems way more advanced than mine and things I have no understanding of.
I'm using Arial in the example since I know it's available, but in reality I want to use Inter for consistency with my program. It's installed on my main system, so it should be available. Is it as simple as setting \setmainfont{Inter} once the error is cleared?
EDIT: That error has been fixed, but now everything after section 1 header gives me undefined sequence control errors:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % Set 1-inch margins on all sides
\usepackage{amsmath} % For math formatting
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\title{HeMan Calculations and Error Propagation}
\author{ohshitgorillas, Ph.D.}

\maketitle

\section*{1. Raw QMS Data}

\subsection*{1.1 Introduction}
This section covers the treatment of raw QMS data, including baseline correction, raw data fitting, and error propagation.
\section{2. Sequence Data}
\subsection{2.1 Introduction}

This section covers the calculation of ncc volumes and error propagation for the entire sequence. Here, we will calculate:
\begin{itemize}
    \item ncc volumes and errors for each standard and blank
    \item the sequence-wide statistics for standards and blanks (ratio mean and errors, etc)
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

I don't know why, but there are so many errors in my document and I have no idea what any of them mean:

First error: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) -- I am ignoring this because the file compiles with these errors just fine, at least it did before the rest of the errors
Second error on \section{Sequence Data}: two "Undefined control sequence" errors
Third error on "This section covers the calculation of ncc volumes and error propagation for the entire sequence. Here, we will calculate:": You can't use 'macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode (what???)
Fourth error on \begin{itemize}: Missing $ inserted
Fifth error on "    \item{the sequence-wide statistics for standards and blanks (ratio mean and errors, etc)}": missing $ inserted, missing } inserted
Please help!! I have no idea what any of these things mean! The document worked just fine up until I changed the font, now I took the font change away and it's still broken af.
EDIT2: Adding and removing the fontspec package cleared those errors, because that makes perfect sense. It's totally normal for something that goes away and then comes back to completely change the behavior of a program. Totally 100% normal.
Now the recipe is terminating with an error but it won't tell me what the error is or where, except that when I remove the fontspec package, it works fine. Is fontspec something I need to install?

\setmainfont is defined by the fontspec package, not fontenc.

Welcome to the site. Besides what Ulrike said, you want a small d in \begin{document}

Thanks! I figured it was something stupid like that. Now everything after the section 1 header is giving undefined control sequence errors. Added to the post.

Add \end{document}?

excluded from the example, but present in the real document. I've added it to the example.

Hmmm. It compiles on my system. (By the way, remove the asterisks and your sections and subsections will be numbered automatically.)

Updated with a screenshot of the code showing five distinct errors. I have no idea what any of them mean or what I'm doing wrong.

I've discovered that the errors only occur when I add \usepackage{fontspec}. is this something I have to install?

No, taking fontspec away and then adding it back resolved the errors. What the f@#$ is happening??? I still can't set the font as setmainfont causes an uncontrolled sequence error

No, now setmainfont no longer causes an uncontrolled sequence error. Now only adding fontspec causes the script to refuse to compile.

fontspec needs lualatex or xelatex for the compilation. You can't use it with pdflatex (and then you also can't use \setmainfont + Arial). (But I'm guessing, as you didn't show the actual error message).

if you use lualatex your example runs without error (although \setmainfont should be before \begin{document}). If you use pdflatex you get the error ! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX because you can not use fontspec with pdftex. To use pdftex remove \usepackage{fontspec} and \setmainfont{Arial}

It is very hard to help you if you do not show the error messages you got.,  You will not get an uncontrolled sequence error tex has no such message.

You have not said what program you are using, or what error message you got, you have mentioned some error messages but have not shown any code that generates them.

I am using MikTex and VSCode, not sure if that answers your question. Not even sure where to find the error. Maybe pdflatex: gave an error in previous invocation of latexmk.? How do I switch to luatex?

I honestly can't even understand half of the instructions for switching to another pdf builder... what have I gotten myself into

Begin by getting it to compile without changing the font. Remove \usepackage{fontspec} and \setmainfont{Arial} by putting a % at the start of those lines. That way you can check it works with the default fonts and whichever compiler VSCode uses by default (presumably pdfTeX). An overfull box is not an error, but a warning. Ignore the warnings until you eliminate the errors. If TeX gives you an undefined control sequence error, it will also tell you which control sequence is undefined & the line number it occurs on. Re persistence: TeX reuses data it writes to files on later runs.

Don’t despair: when I started using LaTeX, there were days I felt like throwing my laptop out the window, but I got past that. Until you’re more comfortable with it, you may want to try Overleaf; https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400825 will show you how to use luatex as your compiler on Overleaf.

as Thérèse says start by removing fontspec and \setmainfont then your example will work without error with your existing pdflatex configuration, and you will be able to get started.

What a wild ride! I finally resolved this by switching my pdf writer to xelatex. This is done by locating and editing the file settings.json and adding the following:
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "tools": ["xelatex"]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "command": "xelatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


"switching my pdf interpreter to xelatex." xelatex does not interpret (read) PDF, it is the generator (writer) of pdf.

thank you, I've corrected my answer
