# Drawing ER diagram with TikZ/Graphviz/dot2texi

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, dot2texi

I want to draw an ER diagram using these combinations of packages. I have tried to follow and re-create [this guide](https://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT015/drawing-ER-diagrams-with-TikZ.pdf), Figure 6.

The graph has to be drawn in an Overleaf document, which leaves me with some issues. I have so far managed to [enable `--shell-escape`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291413/134641), so that `dot2texi` can compile, but I still get:

> Package `dot2texi` Warning: Conversion of `output-dot2tex-fig1.dot`
> failed.

I have no idea how to proceed, and actually get this to work within Overleaf and output as a TikZ graphic.

So far the package setup is this:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, shapes}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
```

The TikZ sets are set up like this:

```
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\tikzset{entity/.style={draw=coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
\tikzset{attribute/.style={draw =coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
\tikzset{multi attribute/.style={draw =coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
\tikzset{derived attribute/.style={draw =coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
\tikzset{simple relation/.style={-}}
\tikzset{total relation/.style={-, double, double distance=1.5pt}}
\tikzset{relationship/.style ={diamond, draw=coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
```

The graph I'm trying to draw is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{dot2tex}[styleonly, mathmode, codeonly, neato, options = - s]
digraph G{
edge [style ="simple relation"];
// nodes
Person [style ="entity"];
pid [ style ="attribute" , label ="\underline{ID}"];
Attribute [ style ="attribute"];
Name [ style ="attribute"];
Phone [ style ="multi attribute"];
Address [ style ="attribute"];
Street [ style ="attribute"];
City [ style ="attribute"];
Age [ style ="derived attribute"];
Uses [ style ="relationship"];
Tool [ style ="entity"];
tid [ style ="attribute" , label ="\underline{ID}"];
tname [ style ="attribute" , label ="Name"];
// edges
Person -> pid;
Person -> Attribute;
Person -> Name;
Person -> Phone;
Person -> Address -> Street;
Person -> City;
Person -> Age;
Person -> Uses;
Tool -> tid;
Tool -> tname;
Tool -> Uses [ style ="total relation"];
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

From the compiler log I can see that `--shell-escape` is correctly enabled: `**main.tex --shell-escape`.

This is the error from the compilation log:

```
Opening dot2tex stream output-dot2tex-fig1.dot
runsystem(dot2tex --codeonly -ftikz   --styleonly   --prog=neato -tmath  -o output-dot2tex-fig1.tex - s output-dot2tex-fig1.dot)...executed.


Package dot2texi Warning: Conversion of output-dot2tex-fig1.dot failed..


Package dot2texi Warning: Please convert output-dot2tex-fig1.dot manually.
```

The compiler is set to LuaLaTeX. The entire code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, shapes}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\tikzset{entity/.style={draw=coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
\tikzset{attribute/.style={draw =coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
\tikzset{multi attribute/.style={draw =coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
\tikzset{derived attribute/.style={draw =coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}
\tikzset{simple relation/.style={-}}
\tikzset{total relation/.style={-, double, double distance=1.5pt}}
\tikzset{relationship/.style ={diamond, draw=coolblack, fill=coolblack!20}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{dot2tex}[styleonly, mathmode, codeonly, neato, options = - s]
digraph G{
edge [style ="simple relation"];
// nodes
Person [style ="entity"];
pid [ style ="attribute" , label ="\underline{ID}"];
Attribute [ style ="attribute"];
Name [ style ="attribute"];
Phone [ style ="multi attribute"];
Address [ style ="attribute"];
Street [ style ="attribute"];
City [ style ="attribute"];
Age [ style ="derived attribute"];
Uses [ style ="relationship"];
Tool [ style ="entity"];
tid [ style ="attribute" , label ="\underline{ID}"];
tname [ style ="attribute" , label ="Name"];
// edges
Person -> pid;
Person -> Attribute;
Person -> Name;
Person -> Phone;
Person -> Address -> Street;
Person -> City;
Person -> Age;
Person -> Uses;
Tool -> tid;
Tool -> tname;
Tool -> Uses [ style ="total relation"];
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

What I would like to have is the graph in the TikZ envoirment, so that it can be included within the PDF produced by Overleaf.

What do I need to do, to compile and include this graph in the Overleaf PDF?

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, this had nothing to do with Overleaf. Fixing my  indentation did the trick:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{dot2tex}[styleonly, mathmode, codeonly, neato, options=-s]
digraph G {
    edge[style ="simple relation"];
    // nodes
    Person [style ="entity"];
    pid [style ="attribute", label ="\underline{ID}"];
    Attribute [style ="attribute"];
    Name [style ="attribute"];
    Phone [style ="multi attribute"];
    Address [style ="attribute"];
    Street [style ="attribute"];
    City [style ="attribute"];
    Age [style ="derived attribute"];
    Uses [style ="relationship"];
    Tool [style ="entity"];
    tid [style ="attribute" , label ="\underline{ID}"];
    tname [style ="attribute" , label ="Name"];
    // edges
    Person -> pid;
    Person -> Attribute;
    Person -> Name;
    Person -> Phone;
    Person -> Address -> Street;
    Person -> City;
    Person -> Age;
    Person -> Uses;
    Tool -> tid;
    Tool -> tname;
    Tool -> Uses [ tyle ="total relation"];
    }
\end{dot2tex}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/134641)! Assuming this completely resolved your problem, please [Accept your own answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1853/134641).